# Firebase - EU data laws

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have an application which is using Firebase realtime database.
A potential new client asked us about the data location. In the UK the laws say this: “not transferred outside the European Economic Area without adequate protection” (https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/principle-8-international/)

But what is that means?

Here is the actual google privacy shield: https://www.privacyshield.gov/participant?id=a2zt000000001L5AAI

Can I store customer data like email address and post address in Firebase realtime database as a UK company?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues instead of directly about programming or coding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal issue

Answer (score 2):

1.5: Data Storage. Unless otherwise provided for by the Paid Services, Customer Data will be stored in the United States ("Hosting Data Location"), except that the Hosting Data Location may not apply to Customer Data copied by Customer or a Customer's End User to another location or used with other Google products and services.

Please read their [terms of service](https://firebase.google.com/terms/billing)

Other Google cloud platform may have different location, e.g.:

1.4 Data Location. Customer may select where certain Customer Data will be stored (“Data Location Selection”), and Google will store it there in accordance with the Service Specific Terms. If a Data Location Selection is not covered by the Service Specific Terms (or a Data Location Selection is not made by Customer with respect to any Customer Data), Google may process and store the Customer Data anywhere Google or its agents maintain facilities. By using the Services, Customer consents to this processing and storage of Customer Data. Under this Agreement, Google is merely a data processor.

(Refer to their [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/terms/) as well)

Comment: But 1.5 about the Data Storage and Hosting service, not about the Realtime Database.

Comment: @wntsmk I haven't personally dig into the physical location, but one of my PhD colleague was working on SLAs and he always reminds people to read the ToS. I do assume the answer must be able to be found in their ToS, if not the one I referred to. If not, you'd better contact Firebase directly - it is simple and quick!

Comment: so does it mean you can store data inside EU borders?